# Is a Request to Stay Case Pending Appeal Considered an Equitable Remedy in the USA?

Tags: united-states, new-jersey, appeal, equity, injunctions

A request for injunctive relief is an equitable remedy and courts have broad discretion in granting or denying it.

Is a request to stay case pending appeal also considered an equitable remedy?

Answer (score 1):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Yes: "The remedy sought by the appellant [a stay pending appeal] is an equitable one.  To be accorded such equitable relief, the applicant must come to the court with clean hands." *National Bank Financial Ltd. v. Barthe Estate*, [2013 NSCA 127, at para 26](https://canlii.ca/t/g1sbx#par26).

In Canada, courts of appeal are statutory courts so all their power derives from statute, but some of those powers (such as the power to grant a stay pending appeal) are still understood to be equitable powers.